# Insert data from modal, Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to insert the input data from a modal but I don't know how to achieve this. I'm not really familiar with AJAX(I apologize for that). I did some readings and research but I'm getting confused. Here is my modal content `reserve_form.php`

```
<form action="" id="book-form">
        <div class="row flex-lg-row-reverse align-items-center pt-1">
            <h3>Reservation Details</h3>
            <div class="col-10 col-sm-8 col-lg-6">
                <input type="hidden" name="package_id" value="<?php  ?>">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="date_start" class="control-label">Reserve Date:</label>
                    <input type="date" name="date_start" id="date_start" class="form-control form-conrtrol-sm rounded-0" min="<?php echo date("Y-m-d") ?>" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d") ?>" required>
                </div>
                <div id="msg" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div id="check-availability-loader" class="d-none">
                    <center>
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center col-md-6">
                            <strong>Checking Availability...</strong>
                            <div class="spinner-border ml-auto" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                        </div>
                    </center>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="quantity" class="control-label">Number of Person <span><i>(Max. of 15 person)</i></span></label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control form" required name="person" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="amount" class="control-label">Additional Inclusions</label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="inclusion" name="inclusion" value="">
                        <label for="inclusion"> Unlimited Samgyupsal &amp; Al Fresco dining experience</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="amount" class="control-label">Total Amount</label>
                    <input type="number" name="cost" id="amount" class="form-control form-conrtrol-sm rounded-0 text-right" value="<?php echo isset($cost) ? number_format($cost, 2) : 0.00 ?>" required readonly>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter First Name" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="lastname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Contact</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="contact" placeholder="09xx-xxx-xxxx" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="email" placeholder="example@email.com" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer py-2">
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" name="details">Save</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary "><span class="close-sm">Close</span></button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Here's my modal in `view.php`

```
<!-- Modal content -->

<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header py-1">
        <h3><?php echo $packages->title; ?></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body py-2">
        <?php $this->load->view('forms/reserve_form'); ?>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Here' my Controller(page.php)

```
public function reservation_details()
  {
    $details = array();
    $details2 = array();

    if ($this->input->post('details')) {
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'First Name', 'required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Last Name', 'required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('contact', 'Contact', 'required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('date_start', 'Reserve Date', 'required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('person', 'Number of Person', 'required|max_length[15]');

      if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
        $details = array(
          'firstname' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
          'lastname' => $this->input->post('lastname'),
          'contact' => $this->input->post('contact'),
          'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        );
        $this->UI_model->reserve_details($details);

        $details2 = array(
          'date_start' => $this->input->post('date_start'),
          'person' => $this->input->post('person'),
          'inclusion' => $this->input->post('inclusion'),
        );
        $this->UI_model->reserve_add($details2);
      }
    }
  }
```

Here's the Model

```
public function reserve_details(){
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $this->db->insert('clients', $data);

            return $this->db->insert_id();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function reserve_add(){
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $this->db->insert('book_list', $data);

            return $this->db->insert_id();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Also, I'm trying to insert the data for multiple tables. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks! Is is also fine to place the submit button at modal footer? or it should be at reserve.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing data array through these functions.

1. `$this->UI_model->reserve_details($details);`
2. `$this->UI_model->reserve_add($details2);`

But in the model, you're not catching those.

1. `public function reserve_details(){`
2. `public function reserve_add(){`

---

So it should be

1. `public function reserve_details($data){`
2. `public function reserve_add($data){`

Since you're checking `if (!empty($data)) {` its always retuns `false`, unless **Undefixed Varibale** error.